# ILOM (Integrated Lights Out Manager) "Too many users are logged in" message

Tags: sun

Upon entering the web interface of a sun server and when trying to login the following message appears:

> Too many users are logged in

Can anyone advise me on what this means, or how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe a bit obvious, but: 1) How many users are allowed to log in at the same time? 2) How many are logged in.  3) Is the answer to 2 less then the answer to 1?

Comment: You might want to reset the Management Processor.

Comment: You can probably reset the ILOM form its command line interface. If someone *does* have an open session, [see who's logged-on](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19203-01/820-1188-12/core_ilom_usrmgmt.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have a read of [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19469-01/820-6412-12/820-6412-12.pdf) which but in brief connect to the service processor cli

```
ssh ip_of_sp
-> show /SP/sessions
```

should tell you who is connected so you my be able to track someone down and get them to log out. Failing that

```
-> reset /SP
```

Will restart the service processor and amongst other things lo everyone out.